Java/Swing: Can't get JScrollPane to show entire element
The goal is to draw a bunch of circles (each a separate JComponent instance) onto a JPanel, and to be able to scroll far enough in any direction to see all of them.
Here is the "main" code:
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(new Circle(-100, 0, 200));
panel.add(new Circle(-25, 0, 650));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (panel);
frame.add(scrollPane);
frame.setSize(600, 600);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);

Here is the Circle class:
public class Circle extends JComponent {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int width;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int width) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width);
    }
}

A couple of problems I can't seem to solve:

JPanel doesn't show any circles unless its layout is set to BorderLayout; when it is set to BorderLayout, it only shows the last circle that has been added to it.
I tried using a JScrollPane to make the JPanel scrollable. However, when I draw an oversized circle to check if it works, JScrollPane doesn't show a scrollbar to see all of it. (See image below)

Unscrollable, can't see entire component.
Hopefully this is halfway understandable, I'm very very new to Swing. Any ideas would be super highly appreciated!

You can't just add multiple components to the CENTER of a panel using a BorderLayout. Only the last component added will be displayed. If you need multiple circles, the better approach is to have a single component with an ArrayList containing information about the Circle. Then the paintComponent() method will iterate through the ArrayList and paint each component. Check out Custom Painting Appraoches for more information and a complete working example.

When doing custom painting on a custom component you will need to override the getPreferredSize() method of the panel to determine the size based on the location and size of the circles added to the ArrayLIst. Scrollbars only work when the preferred size of the panel is greater than the size of the scroll pane. Also, you won't see the start of the circle because you gave it a negative starting value, which means the circle will paint outside of the panel. The scroll pane will not automatically scroll it into view. So you need to make sure the x/y location is not negative.

My gut feeling is that this isn't the best approach - instead of having an individual component represent each circle, you should have a single component which can draw all the circles

Thank you both for the suggestions, I'll try them today and update accordingly! @MadProgrammer I went for the multiple-component approach because I want to eventually make each circle display information specific to it on hover. Would that be possible if they all make up a single component?

The circles are separate instances of a plain Java getter/setter class.  The single component, a drawing JPanel, draws the individual circles.  So yes, each circle can have specific information.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the Performing Custom Painting section.

Your reason for separate  components is valid though it would have been better had you stated it upfront. You should have no problem if you implement getPreferredSize as was mentioned above and choose the correct layout manager. FlowLayout will at least ensure that you keep seeing them added though only you know if the result is how you want them arranged. BoxLayout might be an option.

I want to eventually make each circle display information specific to it on hover - Did you follow the link I provided.? It uses a custom object to contain information about the shape being painted. There is no reason you can't include "hover information".

Diagnosis:
The first problem is not taking into account the dimensions of the
screen you are working with.
The second problem is that you assign the JScrollPane to the Frame and not to the JPanel, which must scroll to show the drawn objects.
The third problem is using BorderLayout, which limits you to representing the objects in the center, this has been mentioned by a colleague in his comments. Although this would be the least serious.
Why should you take screen size into account?
Because you must imagine that you have a sheet or canvas on which you want to paint a circle, said cloth has dimensions of 1x1 meters, while your circle has a radius of 0.75 meters, which would give a diameter of 1.50 meters, which clearly does not It would fit entirely on the sheet or canvas.
As you explained that you are new, I would recommend separating the objects (JFrame, JPanel and Circle) into different classes to make it easier for you to identify any problem, to play with the values of the elements and learn how each one of them works. .
This separation of classes is not mandatory, but it is highly recommended, especially when your projects grow. Rest assured, you don't want to run into gigantic classes that do a lot of things (including confusing you).
With this in mind, I wrote a solution, which I hope will help you:
Main class
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import circlepanel.CirclePanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circles in a JPanel");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            CirclePanel circlePanel = new CirclePanel();
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(circlePanel);
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

            frame.add(scrollPane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

CirclePanel class
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import circle.Circle;

public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6595277960964126231L;
    private List<Circle> circles;

    public CirclePanel() {
        
        circles = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // Examples of circles
        circles.add(new Circle(50, 50, 30));
        circles.add(new Circle(150, 100, 20));
        circles.add(new Circle(800, 800, 650));
       
        /*
        // Calculate panel size based on circles and window size
        int maxX = circles.stream().mapToInt(c -> c.getX() + c.getRadius()).max().orElse(0);
        int maxY = circles.stream().mapToInt(c -> c.getY() + c.getRadius()).max().orElse(0);
        int preferredWidth = Math.max(maxX + 10, 1800); // Adjust the width to 1880 depending on the desired window size
        int preferredHeight = Math.max(maxY + 10, 1400); // Adjust the height to 1400 according to the desired window size
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(preferredWidth, preferredHeight));
        */
        
     // Calculate panel size based on circles and window size            
        int maxX = 0;
        int maxY = 0;
        for (Circle circle : circles) {
            maxX = Math.max(maxX, circle.getX() + circle.getRadius());
            maxY = Math.max(maxY, circle.getY() + circle.getRadius());
        }
        int preferredWidth = Math.max(maxX + 10, 1880); // Adjust the width to 1880 depending on the desired window size
        int preferredHeight = Math.max(maxY + 10, 1400); // Adjust the height to 1400 according to the desired window size
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(preferredWidth, preferredHeight));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Draw the circles
        for (Circle circle : circles) {
            g.drawOval(circle.getX() - circle.getRadius(), circle.getY() - circle.getRadius(),
                    2 * circle.getRadius(), 2 * circle.getRadius());
            
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(circle.getX() - circle.getRadius(), circle.getY() - circle.getRadius(), 2 * circle.getRadius(), 2 * circle.getRadius());
        }
    }
}

Circle Class
public class Circle {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int radius;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int radius) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
}

In the CirclePanel class there is a portion of commented code, which is replaced by the code immediately following it.
The commented code is looking for the maximum radius, x-axis and Y-axis size of all the example circles through Lambda expressions that are more efficient. The code that follows is somewhat more traditional, iterating with a FOR through the ArrayList that contains the circle objects defined as examples.
I hope it helps you, and as a tip, consult the API of the Java version you are using to achieve a more complete knowledge about the components you want to use, and if possible, consult it in your free time, it will greatly expand your perspective. .
Lastly, don't forget to maximize the JFrame so that both scroll panels appear.
